# Quick conversion of number to truth table

Tags: c++, binary

I have a device which I set values in range to with a mask, my code for which looks like this:

```
std::map<double, int> bit_map = {                                                                 
        {0,     0x0},                                                                                 
        {0.5,   0x1},                                                                                 
        {1.0,   0x2},                                                                                 
        {2.0,   0x4},                                                                                 
        {4.0,   0x8},
        {8.0,   0x10},                                                                                
        {16,    0x20}                                                                                 
};                                                                                                    

void set_attenuation(double dBm)                                                        
{           
        if (dBm < 0 || dBm > 31.5) {
                throw std::runtime_error("Invalid dBm");                                              
        }                                                                                             
        
        int mask = 0x0;
        for (auto it = bit_map.rbegin(); it != bit_map.rend(); ++it) {
                if (dBm >= it->first) {
                        mask |= it->second;
                        dBm -= it->first;
                }
        }
        write(mask);
}
```

So for example if I input '23.0' then I expect to return 0x1011100 (hitting 16, 4, 2 and 1 in the map). This works fine, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way of achieving the same?

Comment: I think you don't need a map at all because second is always 2 * first.

Comment: Or you could use a `std::vector<std::pair<double, int>>`.

Comment: Also: `for (const auto & it : bit_map) {if (dBm >= it.first) {mask |= it.second;dBm -= it.first;}`

Comment: Agree with Jabberwocky. This looks like straightforward math; converting decibels to a number of half-decibel steps. That's just `int(dBm*2)`.